# In which case does strategy pattern fail over inheritence

Tags: java, design-patterns

The design principle says that favor composition over inheritance. But I would like to know if there is a case where we can use only inheritance and not composition.

Essentially I am looking at a case where strategy pattern fails over inheritance.

Comment: Define "failing". Are you talking about a situation which simply can not be expressed with a Strategy or one where a strategy is an inferior alternative in regards to readability, performance, maintainability or something else?

Comment: I would like to know a simple situation where strategy pattern creates more maintenance overhead when compared to inheritance.

Comment: why strategy pattern? what's so special about that pattern over all the other patterns?

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion you can emulate all of the behavior of inheritance via composition.

That being said, inheritance can, in some cases, be helpful to guarantee type safety or the existence of a reasonable fallback.

An example where you are forced to use inheritance is when you must interact with an external lib that expects a certain type to be passed, so, if you want to extend that type's behavior, you have no choice but to extend it.

**If you control the overall design of your application, then favor using interfaces to guarantee type safety and method signatures, and composition to create behavior.**

Also, if you haven't already, and are the least bit serious about programming in Java, I would recommend that you read [Effective Java 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

It's probably the best book on Java patterns and good practices there is, and no matter you skill level today, if you haven't read it, you'll learn some useful things.

Comment: Another one: When you want to use parent's protected members